# AudioKit playgrounds (Error : 'Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2')

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audiokit

im using Xcode8 (version 8.2.1) and work properly with the framework 'AudioKit'(version 3.7.1), 
but, but! 
i can't open the file 'AudioKitPlaygrounds.xcodeproj' 
because the my swift version is '3.0.2' but 
the version of playground Project is swift'3.1'

Error

> "Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.0.2: /Users/macbookpro/Documents/XCODE/*AUDIOKIT*/AudioKitPlaygrounds/AudioKitPlaygrounds/AudioKit.framework/Modules/AudioKit.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule"

i can change the swift version on my Xcode8 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need Xcode8.3 to have Swift 3.1

Comment: how can i update Xcode to version 8.3 ?? i have only versione 9 option..

Comment: Developers can grab most old versions of Xcode here https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: Oh Aurelius! what honor to hear, hello! thank you very much, I'm downloading the right version! I take advantage of it to make you my compliments! u are a great!! the best framework ever created! Thank you!